# oracle connection String with C# using oledb

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, oledb

Im developing an application in C# that connects to Oracle 10g.

When I use ODP. Net and this

Connection String **"Data Source=Angelo-HP/XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456"** 
I can connect and perform any action with the database,

but when I use OleDbConnection (System.Data.OleDb) with this

connection String: **"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;PLSQLRSet=true;User ID=mapfre;password=123456;Data Source=XE"** 
I got this error:

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

When I try use Open() method from OleDbConnection.

I think is not oracle configuration because I can connect from ODP and sqldeveloper client.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the tns names setup correctly on your oracle client? %oraclehome%\network\admin

Comment: Your DataSource value is different in both connection string examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try the connection strings at the link below:

[Oracle Connection String Samples](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-msdaora)

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur if you have multiple versions of oracle on your computer.

try these steps

1. go to network folder of oracle and open tnsnames.ora
2. search for the your DB name (XE in this case)
3. this will have your data source information (EX : (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = xx.xx.xx.xx)(Port = xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = XP))))
4. use this in Data source field of your connection string . (EX: Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = xx.xx.xx.xx)(Port = xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = XP)));")

also, make sure your solution was built in anyCPU mode and make sure in App Pool enable 32 bit is true